# Firefox freezes when typing into forms

Tags: nexus-4, firefox-for-android

Experiencing freezes or slowness of Firefox (current and beta version) on a Nexus 4 using Android v.4.3, only when typing into forms. I've read on Mozilla support that it was a known problem and that is could be solved using the [Nightly build of the browser](http://nightly.mozilla.org/).

However, using a *tests only* build is not sastisfacting. I don't know what to do to get a better diagnostic for this issue, any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a known issue, and it's already fixed in the nightly builds, then you shouldn't have long to wait before the fix reaches the stable version. If you can't wait that long, then the [Firefox beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox_beta) offers a middle-ground, and will probably get the fix sooner.

If you know enough programming, you could try and make your own Firefox build that consists of the stable branch with this one bugfix merged into it. (If you don't know how you would do this, you shouldn't attempt it.) But if the fix is non-trivial, your custom build is more likely to have bugs than even the nightly, because your build won't have had even the minimal testing that the nightly gets.